# How can i tell if my HS-485HB Servo is an Increased Rotation servo?

Tags: rcservo

Our Robotics Team (Go [TuxedoPandas](http://tuxedopandas.org)! ordered a mix of regular and "Increased Rotation" servos from Servo city.

However,it appears only the outside packaging is marked. And only with a sticker.

Is there any visual indication on the servo that it is Increased Rotation?

[image]

Comment: How many degrees does it rotate?

Comment: what does this mean? `Increased Rotation`

Comment: I can't see any specific difference. In testing it has a greater (about 10 degrees at each end of rotation). But it varies a little bit.

Comment: Typically when you make an order like this, the supplier provides some kind of receipt with contact information. When that is the case and you have questions about your order, you should contact them or the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

An 'Increased Rotation' servo will not have a distinctive difference just by looking at the outside.  It will become apparent when you plug it in and run it with a servo controller.  This servo will rotate approximately 0.2 degrees per microsecond change in signal.  This means it'll yield approximately 180 degrees provided a 1050-1950usec signal (change in 900usec * 0.2 degrees per usec).  A stock servo, given the same signal range would rotate approximately 90 degrees since it moves about 0.1 degrees per usec.

Comment: And when you find out which is which, put a small label on them!